# chart.CumReturns legend.loc="right" giving "Error in legend"

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I'm trying to do a cumulative returns chart, which is working great till I try and add a legend.
Here is the line that works fine:

```
chart.CumReturns(All.dat[,1], wealth.index = FALSE, geometric = TRUE)
```

and here is the line that gives an error:

```
chart.CumReturns(All.dat[,1], wealth.index = FALSE, geometric = TRUE, legend.loc = "right")
```

Here is the error:

> ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in legend(x = lc$x, y =
> lc$y, legend = legend.names, xjust = lc$xjust, : 'legend' is of length 0

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just tried with an example data "edhec" from manuals, code works fine, please share an example data, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: Maybe a workaround could be to add legend manually? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30527638/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have a column name. As soon as I named my column this worked fine.